# Зависает GUI при цикле

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Имею простое GUI приложение с двумя кнопками, первая запускает цикл, а вторая должна его остановить. Но при запуске цикла GUI зависает.

```
self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запустить"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Остановить"))

def add_func(self):
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.main)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stopClicked)

def stopClicked(self):
    self.stop = True

def main(self):
    while True:
        x = x+1
        if self.stop == False:
            print('Break')
            break
```

Comment: GUI однопоточный. Если вы отняли у него управление сделав цикл он не получит управление

Comment: @CrazyElf а как это исправить можно ?

Comment: @mikitos59 Можно многопоточность сделать. https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/kompiuternoe-programmirovanie/uchebnik-python/28-mnogopotochnost-v-python